# How to pass values from Python to flex

Tags: python, apache-flex, python-3.x

I am calling Python script from flex using HTTP service. How can I send back some values from python to flex app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `HTTPService`, many people will send back XML. Sometimes they'll send back plain text.  In your result handler, you should get the text returned from the service call as [event.result](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/events/ResultEvent.html#result).

Your result handler may look something like this, if you were to return XML:

```
public function onHTTPServiceResult(event:ResultEvent):void{
 var myResult : XML = event.result as XML
 // process XML in some manner
}
```

If you were to return plain text, it may look something like this:

```
public function onHTTPServiceResult(event:ResultEvent):void{
 var myResult : String = event.result as String
 // do something with the String value here
}
```

The only time I've used the latter approach is if the return value is really simple, like a Boolean value (true or false).  The only time I use XML is when I have no control over what the remote service returns.  If at all possible I try to use an AMF Gateway; which will automatically translate server side objects into ActionScript objects.

I can assume that you know how to create a service in Python to output XML or text data.

Comment: actually i am new to python..so have only superficial knowledge..do u have any sample code for creating service in Python? Thanx in advc

Comment: @Flextras: as from the above example i could get how to use the parameters in flex sent from python, but could you pl elaborate how to send values/parameters from python?

Comment: @Sandy I can't; as I don't know anything about Python.  From the perspective of Flex, the backend doesn't matter.  HTTPService just makes a web call to some web page; it is up to you to write that web page.

Comment: @sandy Didn't see your other comment before.  But, in an HTTPService call, parameters aren't really sent back.  You can create an XML Document and then Flex can deal with it that way.  I'll edit my answer if you were to send back plain text.

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing too complex you could try to output xml from Python, then parse that from Flex.

If you're dealing with a lot of data that might generate a large xml file, give [PyAMF](http://www.pyamf.org/index.html) a try.

[image: PyAMF Logo]

HTH

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on how the Python backend is done, ie. what HTTP server code is handling the request sent from Flex. [Here's](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/http.server.html) a link to the Python `http.server` docs, but if the web service is done using something else, such as Django then have a look at their [docs](http://nullege.com/codes/search/django.http.HttpResponse), or have a look at `George Profenza' PyAMF suggestion. I've used the PHPAMF library myself and it makes communicating quite easy, supposedly the PyAMF will do so as well.